# Bluemix / How to Deploy an Executable Standalone Java Application with Embedded Web Services?

Tags: java, executable, ibm-cloud

I'd like to deploy and run a stand-alone Java application under Bluemix, which is already configured and tested locally under an IBM Java 7 JVM. Locally, the executable process works fine when doing a start with the command:

```
java -jar myjar.jar
```

The Java jarfile already contain the Class-Path and Main-Class specified in the default META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file constructed by the MAVEN build.

The image was deployed with the command:

```
cf push myapp1 -p ./target/ibm-myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar -b java_buildpack
```

The Bluemix Cloud Foundry during the push phase installs the runtime for OpenJDK version 8. At the Bluemix console I get the following log message without any further debug details, see the log::

```
2015-12-21T15:07:46.571-0200
[DEA/169]
err
Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2015-12-21T15:07:46.601-0200
[API/0]
out
App instance exited with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278 payload: 
{"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278", 
"version"=>"43d973ae-f849-4a9b-9f70-182e049759de", 
"instance"=>"dbf65f84413f4a4da19f425d726ba4d9", 
"index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", 
"exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout",
"crash_timestamp"=>1450717666}
```

Any hints how debug and circle the root error cause at the Java environment or how to find the error at the application code?

By edit, adding the complete log obtained by a parallel command: cf logs oauth2java --recent

**Log:**

```
2015-12-22T15:37:34.10-0200 [DEA/126]    OUT Removing crash for app with id e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278
2015-12-22T15:37:34.10-0200 [DEA/126]    OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278
2015-12-22T15:37:34.10-0200 [DEA/126]    OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278
2015-12-22T15:42:09.46-0200 [DEA/62]     OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278
2015-12-22T15:42:22.54-0200 [API/3]      OUT App instance exited with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278", "version"=>"148362a7-22a0-4dee-ad3d-e3387329af9b", "instance"=>"4ff542a202154ebca8a70c3be763782f", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"app instance exited", "crash_timestamp"=>1450806142}
2015-12-22T15:42:22.55-0200 [API/2]      OUT App instance exited with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278", "version"=>"148362a7-22a0-4dee-ad3d-e3387329af9b", "instance"=>"4ff542a202154ebca8a70c3be763782f", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to start", "crash_timestamp"=>1450806142}
2015-12-22T16:02:34.42-0200 [DEA/56]     OUT Removing crash for app with id e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278
2015-12-22T16:02:34.42-0200 [DEA/56]     OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278
2015-12-22T16:02:34.42-0200 [DEA/56]     OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278
2015-12-22T16:04:01.83-0200 [API/2]      OUT Updated app with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278 ({"state"=>"STOPPED"})
2015-12-22T16:05:10.21-0200 [API/2]      OUT Updated app with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278 ({"name"=>"myapp1", "memory"=>1024})
2015-12-22T16:13:29.85-0200 [API/0]      OUT Updated app with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278 ({"name"=>"myapp1", "memory"=>1024})
2015-12-22T16:22:52.20-0200 [API/2]      OUT Updated app with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278 ({"name"=>"myapp1", "memory"=>1024})
2015-12-22T16:27:34.21-0200 [DEA/38]     OUT Removing crash for app with id e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278
2015-12-22T16:27:34.21-0200 [DEA/38]     OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278
2015-12-22T16:27:34.21-0200 [DEA/38]     OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278
2015-12-22T16:31:08.81-0200 [API/5]      OUT Updated app with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278 ({"name"=>"myapp1", "memory"=>1024})
2015-12-22T16:32:38.72-0200 [DEA/0]      OUT Got staging request for app with id e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278
[claudef@oc2615188332 ~]$ cf logs myapp1 --recent
Connected, dumping recent logs for app myapp1 in org tester@br.red.com / space dev as tester@br.red.com...

2015-12-22T15:12:37.41-0200 [DEA/21]     OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278
2015-12-22T15:17:09.40-0200 [DEA/110]    OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278
2015-12-22T15:37:34.10-0200 [DEA/126]    OUT Removing crash for app with id e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278
2015-12-22T15:37:34.10-0200 [DEA/126]    OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278
2015-12-22T15:37:34.10-0200 [DEA/126]    OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278
2015-12-22T15:42:09.46-0200 [DEA/62]     OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278
2015-12-22T15:42:22.54-0200 [API/3]      OUT App instance exited with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278", "version"=>"148362a7-22a0-4dee-ad3d-e3387329af9b", "instance"=>"4ff542a202154ebca8a70c3be763782f", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"app instance exited", "crash_timestamp"=>1450806142}
2015-12-22T15:42:22.55-0200 [API/2]      OUT App instance exited with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278", "version"=>"148362a7-22a0-4dee-ad3d-e3387329af9b", "instance"=>"4ff542a202154ebca8a70c3be763782f", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to start", "crash_timestamp"=>1450806142}
2015-12-22T16:02:34.42-0200 [DEA/56]     OUT Removing crash for app with id e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278
2015-12-22T16:02:34.42-0200 [DEA/56]     OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278
2015-12-22T16:02:34.42-0200 [DEA/56]     OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278
2015-12-22T16:04:01.83-0200 [API/2]      OUT Updated app with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278 ({"state"=>"STOPPED"})
2015-12-22T16:05:10.21-0200 [API/2]      OUT Updated app with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278 ({"name"=>"myapp1", "memory"=>1024})
2015-12-22T16:13:29.85-0200 [API/0]      OUT Updated app with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278 ({"name"=>"myapp1", "memory"=>1024})
2015-12-22T16:22:52.20-0200 [API/2]      OUT Updated app with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278 ({"name"=>"myapp1", "memory"=>1024})
2015-12-22T16:27:34.21-0200 [DEA/38]     OUT Removing crash for app with id e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278
2015-12-22T16:27:34.21-0200 [DEA/38]     OUT Stopping app instance (index 0) with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278
2015-12-22T16:27:34.21-0200 [DEA/38]     OUT Stopped app instance (index 0) with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278
2015-12-22T16:31:08.81-0200 [API/5]      OUT Updated app with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278 ({"name"=>"myapp1", "memory"=>1024})
2015-12-22T16:32:38.72-0200 [DEA/0]      OUT Got staging request for app with id e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278
2015-12-22T16:32:45.68-0200 [API/1]      OUT Updated app with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278 ({"state"=>"STARTED"})
2015-12-22T16:32:46.53-0200 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Downloaded app package (4.9M)
2015-12-22T16:32:47.01-0200 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Downloaded app buildpack cache (44M)
2015-12-22T16:32:50.12-0200 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Java Buildpack Version: v3.3 | https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git#378f420
2015-12-22T16:32:50.48-0200 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Downloading Open Jdk JRE 1.8.0_65 from https://download.run.pivotal.io/openjdk/trusty/x86_64/openjdk-1.8.0_65.tar.gz (found in cache)
2015-12-22T16:32:51.66-0200 [STG/0]      OUT        Expanding Open Jdk JRE to .java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre (1.1s)
2015-12-22T16:32:51.81-0200 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Downloading Open JDK Like Memory Calculator 2.0.1_RELEASE from https://download.run.pivotal.io/memory-calculator/trusty/x86_64/memory-calculator-2.0.1_RELEASE.tar.gz (found in cache)
2015-12-22T16:32:51.87-0200 [STG/0]      OUT        Memory Settings: -Xss1M -Xmx768M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=104857K -Xms768M -XX:MetaspaceSize=104857K
2015-12-22T16:32:53.53-0200 [STG/0]      ERR 

2015-12-22T16:33:01.37-0200 [STG/0]      OUT -----> Uploading droplet (48M)
2015-12-22T16:33:13.11-0200 [DEA/0]      OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278
2015-12-22T16:33:25.33-0200 [API/1]      OUT App instance exited with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278", "version"=>"fe1737f1-802c-4c53-acbc-331d78181fc8", "instance"=>"361273f4bc7643ac9e0c600ea6369353", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to start", "crash_timestamp"=>1450809205}
2015-12-22T16:33:25.36-0200 [API/0]      OUT App instance exited with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278", "version"=>"fe1737f1-802c-4c53-acbc-331d78181fc8", "instance"=>"361273f4bc7643ac9e0c600ea6369353", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"app instance exited", "crash_timestamp"=>1450809205}
2015-12-22T16:34:54.60-0200 [DEA/85]     OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278
2015-12-22T16:35:09.41-0200 [API/7]      OUT App instance exited with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278", "version"=>"fe1737f1-802c-4c53-acbc-331d78181fc8", "instance"=>"4fd310e9f1724f149a14ab4a63f49a9c", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"app instance exited", "crash_timestamp"=>1450809309}
2015-12-22T16:35:54.97-0200 [DEA/136]    OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278
2015-12-22T16:36:03.95-0200 [API/7]      OUT App instance exited with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278", "version"=>"fe1737f1-802c-4c53-acbc-331d78181fc8", "instance"=>"b2f3614f1fc34193aada658b24d9985b", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"app instance exited", "crash_timestamp"=>1450809363}
2015-12-22T16:36:54.54-0200 [DEA/67]     OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278
```

**Console Messages:**

```
cf push myapp1 -p ./target/red-oauth-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar -m 1G  --no-route 
Updating app myapp1 in org tester@br.red.com / space dev as tester@br.red.com...
OK

App myapp1 is a worker, skipping route creation
Uploading myapp1...
Uploading app files from: ./target/red-oauth-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
Uploading 10.3M, 3584 files
Done uploading               
OK

Starting app myapp1 in org tester@br.red.com / space dev as tester@br.red.com...
-----> Downloaded app package (4.9M)
-----> Downloaded app buildpack cache (44M)
-----> Java Buildpack Version: v3.3 | https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack.git#378f420
-----> Downloading Open Jdk JRE 1.8.0_65 from https://download.run.pivotal.io/openjdk/trusty/x86_64/openjdk-1.8.0_65.tar.gz (found in cache)
       Expanding Open Jdk JRE to .java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre (1.1s)
-----> Downloading Open JDK Like Memory Calculator 2.0.1_RELEASE from https://download.run.pivotal.io/memory-calculator/trusty/x86_64/memory-calculator-2.0.1_RELEASE.tar.gz (found in cache)
       Memory Settings: -Xss1M -Xmx768M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=104857K -Xms768M -XX:MetaspaceSize=104857K

-----> Uploading droplet (48M)

0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 failing
FAILED
Start unsuccessful

TIP: use 'cf logs myapp1 --recent' for more information
```

Following the hints I found here [ [https://support.run.pivotal.io/entries/80755985-How-do-I-size-my-Java-or-JVM-based-applications-]](https://support.run.pivotal.io/entries/80755985-How-do-I-size-my-Java-or-JVM-based-applications-) 
I did several adjustments at the cloud foundry -m (memory) parameter added to the push command, which automatically configures the Java heap size parameter (-Xmx) and other memory related parameters. The current setting is -m 3G.

The log also throws and error regarding a "CRASHED" with exit-status of 127, which might point to an issue at the port level. I've tried to read the environment variables PORT, VCAP_PORT and VCAP_APP_PORT to identify the active port number. None of them changed the error code.

Further I've downgraded the OpenJDK JVM to version 1.7 to use the same Java release of my local build environment.

See the log below, so far, with the latest changes added, there is no change in the error condition:

```
2015-12-23T08:51:52.09-0200 [STG/0]      OUT        Memory Settings: -Xmx2304M -Xms2304M -XX:PermSize=314572K -XX:MaxPermSize=314572K -Xss1M
2015-12-23T08:51:53.71-0200 [STG/0]      ERR 
2015-12-23T08:52:00.35-0200 [STG/71]     OUT -----> Uploading droplet (39M)
2015-12-23T08:52:10.01-0200 [DEA/71]     OUT Starting app instance (index 0) with guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278
2015-12-23T08:52:17.82-0200 [DEA/71]     ERR Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections
2015-12-23T08:52:17.84-0200 [API/7]      OUT App instance exited with    
guid e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"e69f8f4e-86ed-46d6-9ba2-2d542854c278", "version"=>"6935bc6a-fe72-452b-866c-ec72d1edd3e4", "instance"=>"aef5cf7846e645aca1257331f7aa7b7e", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>127, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1450867937}
```

Comment: Can you try having a second command line window open with cf logs running at the time you do the cf push?  That should capture a more robust error report.

Comment: @ValerieLamkin I've executed a parallel cf log during the execution of the push and added it to the report above by edit. I see an "ERR" message right after the memory setting, but I do not find a pointer, or error message that explains the reason for the "FAILED" condition.

Comment: Seems like maybe your error is right after the memory settings.  Have you confirmed those are correct? 2015-12-22T16:32:51.87-0200 [STG/0]      OUT        Memory Settings: -Xss1M -Xmx768M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=104857K -Xms768M -XX:MetaspaceSize=104857K
2015-12-22T16:32:53.53-0200 [STG/0]      ERR

Comment: @ValerieLamkin I've validated the settings, which results from the parameter -m 2G, trying several adjustments. So far I do not see any change in the error condition, nor could find a log entry that points to the root cause. See the details in the edited section above. Thanks for insights or hints.